# Haskell : Operator Parser keeps going to undefined rather than inputs

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm practicing writing parsers. I'm using [Tsodings JSON Parser video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9RUqGYuGfw) as reference. I'm trying to add to it by being able to parse arithmetic of arbitrary length and I have come up with the following AST.

```
data HVal
  = HInteger Integer -- No Support For Floats
  | HBool Bool
  | HNull
  | HString String
  | HChar Char
  | HList [HVal]
  | HObj [(String, HVal)]
  deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

data Op -- There's only one operator for the sake of brevity at the moment.
  = Add
  deriving (Show, Read)

newtype Parser a = Parser {
 runParser :: String -> Maybe (String, a)
}
```

The following functions is my attempt of implementing the operator parser.

```
ops :: [Char]
ops = ['+']

isOp :: Char -> Bool
isOp c = elem c ops

spanP :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser String
spanP f = Parser $ \input -> let (token, rest) = span f input
                              in Just (rest, token)

opLiteral :: Parser String
opLiteral = spanP isOp

sOp :: String -> Op
sOp "+"  = Add
sOp  _   = undefined

parseOp :: Parser Op
parseOp = sOp <$> (charP '"' *> opLiteral <* charP '"')
```

The logic above is similar to how strings are parsed therefore my assumption was that the only difference was looking specifically for an operator rather than anything that's not a number between quotation marks. It does seemingly begin to parse correctly but it then gives me the following error:

```
λ > runParser parseOp "\"+\""
Just ("+\"",*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:80:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at /DIRECTORY/parser.hs:110:11 in main:Main
```

I'm confused as to where the error is occurring. I'm assuming it's to do with `sOp` mainly due to how the other functions work as intended as the rest of `parseOp` being a translation of the `parseString` function:

```
stringLiteral :: Parser String
stringLiteral = spanP (/= '"')  

parseString :: Parser HVal
parseString = HString <$> (charP '"' *> stringLiteral <* charP '"')
```

The only reason why I have sOp however is that if it was replaced with say Op, I would get the error that the following doesn't exist `Op :: String -> Op`. When I say this my inclination was that the string coming from the parsed expression would be passed into this function wherein I could return the appropriate operator. This however is incorrect and I'm not sure how to proceed.

charP and Applicative Instance

```
charP :: Char -> Parser Char
charP x = Parser $ f
  where f (y:ys)
          | y == x = Just (ys, x)
          | otherwise = Nothing
        f []  = Nothing

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure x = Parser $ \input -> Just (input, x)
  (Parser p) <*> (Parser q) = Parser $ \input -> do
                (input', f) <- p input
                (input', a) <- q input
                Just (input', f a)
```

Comment: Well the `+` sign is not parsed. Exactly what do you pass to the parser?

Comment: I forgot to add that in! I added it in an edit but I do the following in GHCI : `λ > runParser parseOp "\"+\""`

Comment: All the code you posted looks good to me; please also post `charP` and the `Applicative` instance.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I added them !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of `(<*>)` is the culprit. You did not use `input'` in the next call to `q`, but used `input` instead. As a result you pass the string to the next parser without "eating" characters. You can fix this with:

```
instance Applicative Parser where
  pure x = Parser $ \input -> Just (input, x)
  (Parser p) <*> (Parser q) = Parser $ \input -> do
                (input', f) <- p input
                (input'', a) <- q input'
                Just (input'', f a)
```

With the updated instance for `Applicative`, we get:

```
*Main> runParser parseOp "\"+\""
Just ("",Add)
```